# error al subir imagen al servidor guardando el nombre en la base de datos

Tags: php, imagen, servidor

hola tengo un problema al subir una imagen al servidor y guardar el nombre en la BD, sube el nombre de la imagen pero no la guarda en el servidor por que al visualizarla me dice objeto no encontrado pero si me aparece el nombre con el que se guardó en la BD, no logro entender qué es lo que pasa pense que era algo relacionado a la url de las carpetas estuve haciendo cambios pero no resultó exitoso,la estructura es la siguiente:

## addFactura.php

```html
<?php require "controller/factura.php"; ?>

                     <div class="panel-body text-left">
                        
                        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="insertFactura" id="insertFactura" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <label for="imagen">Imagen de la Factura:</label>
                              <input id="imagen" class="form-control" type="file" value="" name="imagen" required="">
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-12">
                          
                              <input type="hidden" name="grabar" value="si" />
                          </div>
                        
                          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4 text-right">
                              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Crear Factura" />
                              <a href="facturas.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
                          </div>
                        
                        </form>
                      </div>
                      
                  </div>
              </div>
```

## controller/factura.php

```js
require 'lib/crud.php';

$mensaje = null;

 
  $Factura = new Crud();

  //Limpiamos los Inputs
    
  #extenciones permitidas
          $extencionPermitida = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'pdf');
     #Carpeta donde se van a guardar las imagenes
          $carpeta ='facturas/';
           #recibimos el campo de la imagen
          $imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
           #Guardamos el nombre original de la imagen en una variable
    $nombrebre_orig = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
           #Codigo para ver la imagen de la variable
          $array_nombre = explode('.',$nombrebre_orig);
          $cuenta_arr_nombre = count($array_nombre);
          $extension = strtolower($array_nombre[--$cuenta_arr_nombre]);
           #validar la extension
           if(!in_array($extension, $extencionPermitida)) { $error = "Este tipo de archivo no es permitido";}
          
          if(empty($error))
          {
        //creamos nuevo nombre para que tenga nombre unico
        $nombre_nuevo = time().'_'.rand(0,100).'.'.$extension;
        //nombre nuevo con la carpeta
        $nombre_nuevo_con_carpeta = $carpeta.$nombre_nuevo;
        //por fin movemos el archivo a la carpeta de imagenes
        $mover_archivos = move_uploaded_file($imagen , $nombre_nuevo_con_carpeta);
        //de damos permisos 777
        chmod($nombre_nuevo_con_carpeta,0777);
   
    }
```

## lib/crud.php

```js
public function upload()
  {
   $file = $this->file;
   $tmp = $this->tmp;
   #si existe el archivo
   if(!empty($file))
   {
    $subir = $file;
    #checamos si existe la Carpeta imagenes si no la creamos
    if(!is_dir("facturas/"))
    {
     mkdir("facturas/", 0777);
    }
    #comprobacion de que se subio el archivo
    if($subir && move_uploaded_file($tmp, "facturas/".$subir))
    {
     return true;
    }
   } return false;
  }
```

## ajax/verFactura.php

```js
<?php
  require_once('../lib/catalogo.php');
<div class="col-md-5">
                      <img src="facturas/<?php echo $imagen; ?>" class="img-responsive center-block img-thumbnail" alt="<?php echo $imagen; ?>"><br>
                  </div>
?>
```

Comment: Hola!, el archivo se encuentra en el folder facturas?, veo que creas un objeto crud ($Factura) pero nunca usas el método upload ($Factura->upload()) si no que lo haces manual y esto hace que sea inecesario usar la librería Crud.

Comment: Hola! facturas es la carpeta que tengo en el servidor para guardar las imagenes que subo. te refieres al archivo crud.php?

Comment: Me refiero a si el archivo que mandas en el formulario se encuentra en la carpeta facturas del servidor

Comment: No logro entender del todo puedes escribir una parte del código al que te refieres te lo agradecere infinitamente, estoy bloqueada : (

Comment: Entra al servidor y revisa el contenido de la carpeta facturas, si hay archivos entonces se debe a error de url o de permiso

Comment: ya investige, funcionaba ant

Comment: como debe ser la estructura de la estructura de la url si lo tengo en servidor externo por ejemplo si mi web es http://maracuya.com.mx en la raiz tengo el index.php la carpeta con imágenes de las facturas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor sería colocar la ubicación completa, esto para asegurar que no importa que página del sitio veas siempre se pueda visualizar. Una forma de hacerlo sería `<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER[‘HTTP_HOST’]?>/facturas/<?php echo $imagen; ?>" class="img-responsive center-block img-thumbnail" alt="<?php echo $imagen; ?>"><br>`

Solo asegurate que la url al final sea algo similar a "tudominio/facturas/factura1.pdf"

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu sugerencia la tomare en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que sea un problema de cómo estás renombrando la imagen, 
    
     `$nombre_nuevo_con_carpeta = $carpeta.$nombre_nuevo;`
    
La estás renombrando por ejemplo:
    "Facturas" + "/" + "Time()" + "rand" , y después la buscas dentro de la carpeta facturas

Comment: estuve haciendo pruebas con otro servidor y los mismo archivos, en el otro si funciona; sera algo relacionado con los permisos? tengo que hacer llamado al usuario y contraseña? aunque le diga en el crud.php que requiere del archivo conexion?